# NetworkManager slows down shutdown and more in Debian 12?

Tags: systemd, networkmanager

#### First problem

Since I last updated my computer earlier this week, my computer started needing about 11 minutes to turn off. At first glance, it is NetworkManager.service and wpa_supplicant.service which cause the problem (their 90s timeout is extended 6 times for a total of 10.5 minutes).

Solution: setting `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=5s` and `DefaultTimeoutAbortSec=5s` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`

#### Second problem

Trying to change any network setting crashes NetworkManager (simple disconnecting the current connection for example). It happens with the GUI and the CLI (`nmcli con down 'WiFi-2.4-xxxx'`).
Consequences:

1. No more WiFi
2. Desktop freezes under KDE (not under gnome which I am using)
3. `sudo` freezes (unable to use sudo) (no clue why)
4. The shutdown popup takes time (a few seconds) to appear.
5. Other shutdown timeout appearing for user@1000.service with 2x2 minutes timeout (my background apps do no longer close).

   Exception: `nmcli con up 'PiVPN'` or `nmcli con down 'PiVPN'` (openvpn) is not causing NetworkManager to crash and the connection works.

#### What I have tried

1. `root@mylinuxpc:~# dpkg-reconfigure network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome wpasupplicant` but without success.
2. Searched on the internet but only found nothing useful.

#### Infos

```
root@mylinuxpc:~# neofetch
       _,met$$$$$gg.          root@mylinuxpc 
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       -------------- 
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64 
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: 82XG IdeaPad Slim 5 16ABR8 
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 6.1.0-15-amd64 
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 11 mins 
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 3173 (dpkg), 39 (flatpak) 
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.2.15 
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 2560x1600 
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         DE: GNOME 43.9 
 `$$b      "-.__              WM: Mutter 
  `Y$$                        WM Theme: Adwaita 
   `Y$$.                      Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
     `$$b.                    Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
       `Y$$b.                 Terminal: gnome-terminal 
          `"Y$b._             CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 7730U with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 
              `"""            GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Barcelo 
                              Memory: 1787MiB / 13825MiB
```

#### Any idea of what I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### FIXED

I just got a kernel update which fixed my problem ! I guess Debian also has its problems.

While NetworkManager is still up and running : `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo reboot`. This will be the last reboot to take time.

If you edited `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, you can remove the changes you made.
`DefaultTimeoutStopSec=5s` -> `#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s`
`DefaultTimeoutAbortSec=5s` -> `#DefaultTimeoutAbortSec=`

New kernel: 6.1.0-16 (the previous one was 6.1.0-15)

```
root@mylinuxpc:~# neofetch
       _,met$$$$$gg.          root@mylinuxpc 
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       -------------- 
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64 
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: 82XG IdeaPad Slim 5 16ABR8 
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 6.1.0-16-amd64 
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 2 mins 
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 3174 (dpkg), 39 (flatpak) 
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.2.15 
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 2560x1600 
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         Terminal: gnome-terminal 
 `$$b      "-.__              CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 7730U with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 
  `Y$$                        GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Barcelo 
   `Y$$.                      Memory: 2036MiB / 13825MiB 
     `$$b.
       `Y$$b.                                         
          `"Y$b._                                     
              `"""
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Debian 12 with a Framework 13" Ryzen 7040.
Reinstalled with the latest NetInstaller but without any success.

01:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter

Already removed the networkmanager and reinstalled it, without success.

KDE freezes after hibernate/sleep. Today i switched to Gnome with kind of the same error.

> systemctl status: 
> wpa_supplicant[1648]: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
>
> Journalctl: wpa_supplicant.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
> Dec 13 16:55:18 systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant.service: Killing process 1112 (wpa_supplicant) with signal SIG>
> Dec 13 16:56:48  systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant.service: Processes still around after SIGKILL. Ignoring.
> Dec 13 16:58:18 systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant.service: State 'final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
> Dec 13 16:58:18 systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant.service: Killing process 1112 (wpa_supplicant) with signal SIG>
> Dec 13 16:59:48 systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant.service: Processes still around after final SIGKILL. Entering >
> Dec 13 16:59:48 systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
> Dec 13 16:59:48 systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant.service: Unit process 1112 (wpa_supplicant) remains running af>
> Dec 13 16:59:48 systemd[1]: Stopped wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant.
>
> JournalCTL errors:
>
> Dec 15 13:22:00 ferdinand-laptop gnome-software[2211]: internal error: failed, but no error code: cancelled
> Dec 15 13:23:00 ferdinand-laptop gnome-shell[2001]: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Object does not exist at path “/org/gnome/Terminal/SearchProvider”
> Dec 15 13:23:00 ferdinand-laptop gnome-shell[2001]: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Object does not exist at path “/org/gnome/Terminal/SearchProvider”

Comment: Maybe you can try to get help on the Framework forum then. If you do, please post the solution here. Thanks to you, I will not waste time reinstalling the whole OS. I also have the issue where the services are still around 'after final SIGKILL'.